# mongodb - append field to BSONObj

Tags: c++, mongodb

mongodb c++ drive construct a BSONObj object by BSONObjBuilder, but in practice there is requirement to append field to BSONObj like:

```
BSONObj base_part_query()
{
    return BSON(...);
}

void q1()
{
    BSONObj obj = base_part_query();
    obj.appendField("q1_special","v"); // mongo driver has no such api
    // query by q1
}
void q2()
{
    BSONObj obj = base_part_query();
    obj.appendField("q2_special","v"); // mongo driver has no such api
    // query by q2
}
```

If I don't make `base_part_query`, there will be n duplicated copy of BSON(...) in qn(). That is not good.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a method:

```
BSONObj o = (mongo::BSONObjBuilder().appendElements(base_part_query())<<"q1_special"<<BSON("$lte"<<111)).obj()
```